# How to load backup to a new table

Tags: postgresql

I am taking a back up of table, creating another table and want to restore the back up into new table i just created.

## Take backup of table_a

```
pg_dump -v -Fc -t table_a -U dba -h <host_name>  db_name > ./pls.dmp
```

## Create table_b

```
CREATE TABLE table_b (LIKE table_a)
```

## Restore back up to table_b

```
pg_restore -v -U dba --data-only -h <host_name> -d db_name -t table_b ./pls.dmp
```

After the restore step, i do not see data in table_b.Am i  missing a step or doing something wrong?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From the `pg_restore` man page:

> --table=table
>
> Restore definition and/or data of only the named table.

This option allows you to select a table that you want to restore *from* the backup. It does not sets the name of a table to restore the backup *to*.

What you want to do is not possible using an option of `pg_restore`. You will have to edit the dump and replace `table_a` with `table_b`.